# Replace string at index in multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I have a hundred files in a directory. They look like

```
abc def
ghi 123456
xyz
```

I want to change `123456` to `XXXXXX`
I cannot use a regex because the string is not always the same but it's always at the same index and has always the same length

What I tried in python 3.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput
import glob

for filepath in glob.iglob('mydir/*.txt'):
    with fileinput.FileInput(filepath, inplace=True) as file:
        for index, line in enumerate(file):
            if index == 1:
                print(line.replace(line[9:14], "XXXXXX"))
```

1- This replaces the whole file with the modified text

2- `123456` is replaced by `XXXXXX6` (9:14 being the real boundaries in my files)

How can I fix this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the replacing, simply write:

```
print(line[:9] + "XXXXXX" + line[14:])
```

Don't bother with `str.replace`; it could lead to unexpected behaviour in this case.

The reason that the original code was leaving the `6` was because slices don't include the final index.

---

To print the whole file, use the following code:

```
for index, line in enumerate(file):
    if index == 1:
        line = line[:9] + "XXXXXX" + line[14:]
    print(line, end="")
```

The `end=""` is because iterating over lines in a file keeps the `\n` character at the end of each line, so we need to tell `print` not to add its own or we get a blank line in between each line of the file.

Comment: Then I use [9:15], but I still have the whole file replaced by the line

Comment: @gyc That's because you're not printing any of the other lines. You're just printing the one that you're replacing in. Use `else:`.

Comment: right, this works but it inserts additional carriage returns (I read somewhere that I need to use end=something as param to print

Comment: @gyc `print(line, end="")` or `print(line[:-1])`. Iterating through lines of a file keeps the new lines on the end; a decision that has annoyed many, many people. To remove them probably also would've annoyed many, many people though, so there's that.